# Javascript - Updating duplicated numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an unordered list like this;

```
list1 = [2,3,1,2,1,3,3,1,2]
```

I want to add +10 to the recurring elements in this list every time. So there should be a list as follows;

```
list1 = [2,3,1,12,11,13,23,21,22]
```

At the same time, the list order must remain intact.

In fact, the list is longer than the example here (10 digits repeat 7 times).

I would be grateful for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Just have a lookup which count the frequency of number and then multiply the frequency with 10 and add the number.

```js
const list1 = [2,3,1,2,1,3,3,1,2],
      lookup = {},
      result = list1.map(number => {
        lookup[number] = (lookup[number] || 0) + 1;
        return number + (lookup[number] - 1) * 10;
      });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey Hassan, It works smoothly and is very useful for my purpose. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
var list1 = [2,3,1,2,1,3,3,1,2];
var countObject = {};

list1.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if(countObject[item]) {
        list1[index] = item + (10 * countObject[item]);
        countObject[item] = countObject[item] + 1;
    } else {
        countObject[item] = 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: It gives `TypeError: list1.foreach is not a function`, it's forEach, not foreach. And it doesn't provide the output the OP specified, this returns `[  2,  3,  1, 12, 11, 13, 13, 11, 12 ]`, but the OP asked for `[ 2, 3, 1, 12, 11, 13, 23, 21, 22]`.

Comment: Hi Majid, Thank you for your suggestion, I will try it

Answer (score 0):

For a compact version, you could take a closure over an object for counting and assign zero to unknown property and increment this value.

```js
const
    list = [2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2],
    result = list.map((o => v => v + 10 * (o[v] ??= 0, o[v]++))({}));

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: Hi Nina, thank you for the suggestion! i will try it